# support multipart POST for apachebench?

Tags: performance, multipart, apachebench

I want to use apachebench (ab) to test file upload performance.
I have read the manual and can't find a way to achieve my goal.

My goal is try to upload a file by a HTTP Request with POST method and multipart/form-data format.

The ab support "-p POST-FILE", but I only can find the format  key=value&key2=value2

What the post data I want to send is

Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryuUlX4554LPBjInc5

------WebKitFormBoundaryuUlX4554LPBjInc5
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="411c40d9.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX (IMAGE DATA)
YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY

I googled for a while and can't find any related article or way to achieve that.
I use cURL and it works fine, but I want to do stress testing.
So I need use ab to achieve that goal.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This may be very late but might help others who were searching for the same thing...

```
$ ab -c 5 -n 5 -v 4 -p example_post.txt -T "multipart/form-data; boundary=miuxupsktcqtriloonfbdudrgtawascl" http://yourapplication.local/upload/
```

Credit to [this guy](http://www.adityamooley.net/blogs/2011/03/21/multipart-posting-with-apache-benchmark/comment-page-1/#comment-30978).

Comment: following up on this answer the contents of the example_post.txt file could be assuming -T "multipart/form-data; boundary=1234567890"  ...  file contents:    --1234567890
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ID"

3
--1234567890
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="videofile"; filename="ab1_pod.avi"
Content-Type: video/x-msvideo

[base64 encoded file content here]
--1234567890--

Comment: @ofer, would suggest posting your command if you need help. In short double check that the .txt file exists in your current directory, you have ab installed, you've closed the quotes and your URL is valid...there maybe a problem if you're pointing to HTTPS where the certificate isn't valid

Comment: i did it - u forgot to mention that you need to use the unix2dos util.
Thanks!

Comment: couldn't make it work as posted, but the linked article had better detail.