# What test harness tool/framework can test concurrent requests in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

How can I test my Rails app with N concurrent users?

These simulated users will do some actions like upload/download files, etc.

Are there any frameworks or free tools that support this?

Comment: Re-wrote the question to better focus it. I hope @KenWhite feels happier with this formulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use jMeter, although the UI is a little rough IMO. I ended up sharing a lot of code between my easyb (Groovy-based) specs and a mini-DSL I used to create jMeter config/execution files (XML) so redundancy between specs and load testing was reduced. The same should be doable in Ruby as well.

JMeter allows concurrent testing, ramp-ups, all sorts of stuff. I don't know if it does everything a commercial tool does, but I've used it for a long time on a wide range if apps and it's been, more or less, satisfactory.

Comment: Anyone here in 2017+ can use https://github.com/flood-io/ruby-jmeter to generate jmeter test plans in Ruby. Makes a powerful combo, although I haven't done deep dive into jmeter yet.

Answer (score 2):

ab(Apache Benchmark) is made for that. Here is an example:

https://github.com/igrigorik/async-rails

Comment: Thank for your suggestion. Ab is a good tool but I can't test uploading file with it, regardless of applying [this instruction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317400/support-multipart-post-for-apachebench).

Then I tried to figure out another tool, and found this [good screencasts](http://www.bestechvideos.com/2009/06/26/railslab-scaling-rails-episode-15-load-testing-part-1) mentioning Apache Bench and Httperf. It seems to me that Httperf is better. Anyway, they are both interesting to try :)